# Managing extension conflict on js files

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, javascript

I have and (community) extension that switches the product images when you change the options of a configurable product. This works great.
I've also developed some extension that changes the `select` elements of the configurable options to images and labels. Again this works as expected.
**Now the issue**. Both of them need to remove from the `head` block the `varien/configurable.js` javascript file that handles the configurable products and add their own file. So basically both of them override the js class `Product.Config`. Both of them need to override the `initialize` function in the class so I cannot add in my extension `Product.Config.prototype.initialize = function(){...}`. **Or can I?**
As you can imagine they don't work together.
**Is there any way to solve these kind of conflicts without cloning the changes that the community extension brings to the table into my js file and building on that?**

Comment: Not sure on the particulars but with Prototype you have inheritance - so you could make your customisations extend the community one and then instantiate your class (for example MyProduct.Config)  instead of Product.Config.

Comment: This means I have to change the line in the configurable products template from `spConfig = Product.Config(...)` to `spConfig = MyProduct.Config(...)`, right? if so, please post this as an answer, maybe add a little example :). My prototype skills could use some improvements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, depending on the code involved you can subclass the prototype Product.Config and inherit from it. So for example something like this:

```
var MyProduct.Config = Class.create(Product.Config, {
    initialize: function($super, config){
        $super(config); //this calls the parent initialize
        //do your custom stuff here        
    }
});
```

More info on prototype's inheritance is [here](http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance).

As you have guessed afterwards you would use

```
spConfig = MyProduct.Config(...)
```

instead of

```
spConfig = Product.Config(...)
```

Comment: What do you know...it works. Indeed I had to change the `spConfig` value, but this doesn't bother me that much since I already have to work with a custom theme, and the `configurable.phtml` file already has some custom code. I've even wrapped it in an if statement `if (typeof MyProduct == 'undefined'){spConfig = Product.Config(...)} else {spConfig = MyProduct.Config(...)}` in case someone disables my extension in the future. Thanks.

Comment: No probs - glad to hear it works.