# Detail description of configurable product price

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, configurable-product, price

I have configurable products on my website.

Suppose there is a product whose base price is `100$` now there are two config product associated with it.

1) color - `3$`

2) size - `2$`

Now what default magento does is it shows 105$ as config price but what i want is, The base price should remain constant and the additional price should be shown separately.

Like : `100$ + 3$ + 5$ : 105$`

I tried to locate it from price.phtml but i think its coming from JS. Can anyone suggest how can this be done or from where should i start digging in.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The js that handles the configuration changes for configurable products is `js/varien/configurable.js`.
You might want to take a look at the function `reloadPrice` inside the `Product.Config` class in the file I mentioned. You can try to change it, so it won't add the prices just compose a string with it.
And in order not to change a core file, take a look at [this explanation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7630/146) by @Fooman on how to extend the js classes in Magento.

Comment: I reviewed the function reloadPrice, There i found funtion `optionsPrice.changePrice()` is used to change the price. Now i want the price to change but in the manner eg : 100+10+12 etc. Also the name of option should be displayed along with price eg: 100 + 10 red color + 12 blue color. I found another function `getOptionLabel` which is used to get the option label. But i don't know how to use it and how to return the value. Can you please help me in it

Answer (score 1):

The price-calculation for configurable products is implemented in file /js/varien/configurable.js

a good start is to digg in is at line: 272
and in line 291 the price will be inserted