# Don't upgrade the price when customer select options in dropdown

Tags: php, configurable-product, price, ce-1.9.0.1

I want to remove the price upgrade when customer select an options in dropdown menu.

IE: If normal price is 100$, and the customer selects a color ( +20 $ ) the price increases to 120$. I don't want the price to change, I'd like it to stay 100$

I'm use `Magento 1.9.0.1` with Rwd theme.

Answer (score 1):

Find your configurable.js . In my project is `js\varien\configurable.js` .Find `this.reloadPrice();` and remove or comment it. Attention this change will effect to whole store.

Ex:

```
configureElement : function(element) {
    .........
    this.reloadPrice();
},
```

Modify to

```
configureElement : function(element) {
    .........
    //this.reloadPrice();
},
```

Comment: This would work but it's not a good idea to modify the core code. Here is how you can rewrite a js class: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7608/146

Answer (score 1):

I used this, and it worked for me.
   drop_down is the class name for your drop down.
   tprice is the ID where you want to show your updated price.

```
$(document).on('change', " .drop_down ", function () {
          var totalprice = 0;
          totalprice= (totalprice + parseFloat(this.value) + parseFloat(pPrice)) ;
          $('#tprice').val(totalprice);
           });
```

In this code, Once the drop down is selected option (Price) doesn't change, once selected.